# Tried to convert datafram to series in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I data framed the following CSV:

[image: 1]

I ran the loop for it:

[image: 2]

The result:

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

When trying to print s out of loop it is only showing the volume column and not the others:

[image: 5]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do read the guidelines for posting questions. Do not post screenshots and links unless absolutely necessary. Produce sample data, code and expected outcome as well as your attempts so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, as you are assigning new Series to s instead of appending it. At the end of the for loop, s will only be the Series containing the volume column.

You can take a look at this [page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) to learn more about appending Series to an existing series.

To be brief you should replace

`s = pd.Series(df2[column])`

you would do the following

`s = s.append(pd.Series(df2[column]))`,

although i'm not sure why you would like to do that! If you go through the documentation you can see that you can reindex while appending by running the following code instead

`s = s.append(pd.Series(df2[column]), ignore_index=True)`